# Capitalize first word in a multiword string in R

Tags: r, string, text

In R, how to capitalize only the first word in each string in a vector of single and multi-worded strings?
The solutions I found (stringr::str_to_sentence(), stringr::str_to_title(), capitalize every word in the string.

Thanks!

```
strings <- c('one', 'one two', 'three four', 'five six')
expected.result <- c('One', 'One two', 'Three four', 'Five six')
```

Comment: In your example, why do you expect the third string of 'three' to become 'Three four five`, and the fourth string of 'five six' to become 'Six seven'?

Comment: `stringr::str_to_sentence` works fine for me, i..e `stringr::str_to_sentence(c('one', 'one two', 'three', 'five six'))` gives `c("One", "One two", "Three", "Five six")`.

Comment: @stefan suggested the same solution like 2 mins ago

Comment: `paste0(toupper(substr(strings, 1, 1)), substr(strings, 2, nchar(strings)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strings <- c("one", "one two", "three four five", "six seven")
```

---

```
stringr::str_to_sentence(strings)
[1] "One"             "One two"         "Three four five" "Six seven"
```

---

Base R:

```
sub("(\\w)", "\\U\\1", strings, perl = TRUE)
[1] "One"             "One two"         "Three four five" "Six seven"
```

Comment: str_to_sentence will return convert "FBI" to lower case "Fbi".